# R apriori algorithm-How to assign top items of ItemFrequency() to a vector?

Tags: r, apriori, arules

I am working in R apriori algorithm which have a function ItemFrequencyPlot() of arules library.

This function create a plot by passing argument (topN).Here we pass (Top N =20) which plot the top 20 items.Basically the function find top items on the  basis of  frequency.The function returns plot image which have top items.

Now My Question is that who assigns these top items to a vector or  how we get these top items in order to perform additional operation.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8FNE.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the most frequent items, you can use the function `itemFrequency`. To get the absolute count of the 20 most frequent items, try

```
itms <- itemFrequency(myTransactions, type = "absolute")
head(sort(itms, decreasing = TRUE), n = 20)
```

Comment: Thanks for this But it gives the following
  whole milk      other vegetables            rolls/buns                  soda 
                 2513                  1903                  1809                  1715 
How can we get the labels only in vector? e.g(whole milk,soda, etc..)

Comment: As per its documentation `itemFrequency` returns a named numeric vector. The labels you are looking for are the names of that vector. Therefore: `names(myFreqItems)`